# No root file system is defined - iso file that skipps some installation steps

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, raid, usb-installation, ahci

**NVMe SSD** please I have this problem with ubunto installation, I have an iso file that skips some installation steps, after that I choose the language, the installation crushes and it shows the message "No root file system defined", I know that I have to do something like this

[Partitioning step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd01k.png)

**I noticed that the usb gets partitioned and all files are cleared after this error.**

**The client that I work for gave me this iso file, I managed to install the ubuntu I downloaded from the official website.**

but I cant reach this step. I am using Dell laptop and I changed from RAID to AHCI in the bios.

Please help

Comment: Primary/Logical? Those look like MBR partition options. The installer should not offer that choice on a GPT system. Perhaps you are seeing a corresponding step for GPT? Or perhaps your clients wants MBR?

Comment: The iso file removes all partitions, that is what the client told me

Comment: I really don't understand all these terms, I booted with usb and first step is to chose the language, I chose English and when I click on next/continue it shows the message "No root file system defined"

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? Are you familiar with GParted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, the ssd I have is NVME so I had to change one file in the bootable usb:
KS.PRESSED
Within this file the following image is specified
[KS.PRESSED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOqBk.png)

In the partitions section replace **/dev/sda** with **/dev /nvme0n1**

This change is made because hi-fi disks, like m2, the interfaces are not identified as the an hdd (Mechanical) or ssd